# Enable Android X for specific application module

Tags: java, android, android-jetpack, androidx

I'm new to Android X library which seems a next version of original Android Support Library. And I decided to migrate my existing project to Android X.

I've got multiple application modules in a single project. There are about 20 application and library modules. As per the [guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/), I'm trying to enable Android X.

My question is if there is any way to enable Android X for the specific module, not for entire project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple way is to Right Click -> Refactor -> Migrate to Android X

According to the docs, you CAN NOT have both AndroidX and Android Support libraries in your project.

It's either all are AndroidX libraries  or all are Android Support libraries.

AndroidX is just the newer version.

But an important point to note is that thought 'Migrate to Android X' refactors libraries as well as the view tags you used, it still can leave some gaping holes.

When I migrated, my RecycerView in Activity.java was useless.
Should something similar happen, don't worry

In java, just try working with importing the relevant androidx packages, that's what solved for me. Though this isn't a frequent issue